# Which is the physical interpretation of the "strange" constant $e \cdot c/ 4 \pi$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

This  constant is assignable to charged leptons $(e, \mu, \tau)$ representing the fraction of their individual magneton $\hat{m}= e \cdot \hbar/ 2  m$ to their Compton-wavelength $\lambda_{C} = h / m  c$:
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{\hat{m}}{\lambda_{C}} = e \cdot c / 4 \pi   [\frac{A}{m} \cdot m^{2}] 
\end{eqnarray*}
Its dimensionality indicates that it determines 
a natural constant of magnetic flux: $4,8 \times 10^{-18} $ [Wb], however only a fraction $4 \alpha$ of the magnetic flux-quantum $\Phi_{0} = h/ 2e$. The constant may thus define magnetic flux in a leptons dipole-field.

Comment: This does not seem to be a question about history, you should ask on Physics SE.

Comment: As a physicist, I can confidently state that it's just another wacky fudge factor.  <-- which happens to correctly predict real world behavior.

Comment: A question like this is really in need of one or more published sources to give it a credible context.